# Reverse not found for my custom model admin urls after reload(sys.modules['urls.py'])

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-1.4

After doing following when I call reverse for my custom model admin url its giving me Reverse not found and before reloading urls.py reverse working fine.

```
def _reset_urls(self, urlconf_modules):
    """Reset `urls.py` for a set of Django apps."""
    for urlconf in urlconf_modules:
        if urlconf in sys.modules:
            reload(sys.modules[urlconf])
    clear_url_caches()

    resolve('/')
```

I debugged this and find out that `admin.site._registry` is empty when I call `reload(sys.modules[urlconf])` because it creates new AdminSite object.

I tried preserving `admin.site` in a variable before `reload(sys.modules[urlconf])` and assigning it back to `admin.site` after reload but it didn't work.

Need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I need this in unittests.

Comment: Not when, _why_ do you need this?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because we are using feature flags in urls.py, so we are patching them in our tests and then reloading it to take effect.

Comment: @knbk please look at the above ^^ comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into the same issue running Django 1.7, this seems to fix it for me:

```
import sys
from importlib import reload  # Python 3
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import clear_url_caches
from django.utils.importlib import import_module

def reload_urlconf(urlconf=None):
    clear_url_caches()
    if urlconf is None:
        urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF
    if urlconf in sys.modules:
        reload(sys.modules[urlconf])
    import_module(urlconf)
```